# How to add items to a ListView during runtime?

Tags: android

How to add items to a ListView in Android during runtime?

Comment: Can you add more details? Like what adapter you are using, code setup etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be an adapter that backs this `ListView`. The Adapter must have taken some datastore(ArrayList etc.) as an argument.

Add your items to this list(the datastore that you've supplied to the adapter) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`() method on your adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, i found a perfect example for this in the Android Sample Project "ApiDemos" (List12.java)